# Drupal 7: read the content of a file from the view module

Tags: file, view, drupal-7

I have added a content type in Drupal 7 this content type contains only a file field :every file have to contain an array like this:

```
'rows' => array(
array(0,0), //(x,y) values
array(90,90),
array(59,70),
array(65,77),
array(85,66),
)
```

I want from the view module to read the content of the file and send the array to the selected graph type: for example the user select a file then a pieChart graph, how the content of the file (array) can be send to the library of the pieChart? Is that possible from the view module? what function have to be added to the view plugin in order to send the content of the file to the selected library?

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you could implement 2 hooks :

- hook_field_formatter_info()
- hook_field_formatter_view()

In this way you will be able to see the formatter in your views field settings. Just select the "File get content" formatter and you're done.

@see => https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2aNJ.png

In a custom module put this code :

```
function mymodule_field_formatter_info() {
    return array(
        'file_get_contents_formatter' => array(//Machine name of the formatter
            'label' => t('File get content'),
            'field types' => array('file'), //This will only be available to file fields
        ),
    );
}

function mymodule_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
    $element = array(); // Initialize the var
    switch ($display['type']) {
        case 'file_get_contents_formatter':
            foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
                $element[$delta] = array('#markup' => empty($item['uri']) ? '' : file_get_contents(file_create_url($item['uri'])));
            }
            break;
    }
    return $element;
}
```

Comment: and how can send the content of the file to another file? Because I want to get the content and send the array to the selected library to draw this values...